# Android Scrollview ignores button at the bottom

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

First of all, I'm new on Android. My Problem is the Following: I want to have a Scrollview (actually with two Texftields and one Button at the Bottom). When the TextInput gets too big, the Button goes too far and I cant scroll up to the button. I think the ScrollView is too big for the Screen.
More Info: I use it as a Fragment of a TabBar and this is my whole fragment.xml-File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tf_margin_leftright"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tf_margin_leftright"
            android:hint="@string/hint_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cj_titleLabel"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tf_margin_leftright"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tf_margin_leftright"
            android:hint="@string/hint_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cj_descriptionLabel"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttontitle_send"
            android:id="@+id/cj_submitButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="submitJob"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Maybe the Error is somewhere here?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Make `android:fillViewport="true".`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help...

Comment: The scroll view should have `layout_height=match_parent` You are defining how big the scrolling window should be, it should not wrap content.

Comment: Make `Scroll View` height to `match_parent`.

Comment: It still doesn't work :( I think the Problem is, that the ScrollView is too high. The Scroll Indicator goes too far down, out of the screen...